# Material UI accordion animation not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm building out an accordion with Material UI, and I noticed that when I have the Accordion directly in my file's return, it works fine. But if I make a sub-component and return it, the animation does not work. Note that opening the accordion is fine, but it suddenly pops open instead of having that smooth transition. Any idea what's causing this?

[Replicated here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-animation-problem-zngqvd?file=/src/App.tsx)

Dependencies in sandbox reflect the version in my package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [re]defining your `QuestionAccordion` component *inside* of your `App` component, so the re-render is happening before the accordion animation can compete.  Define your `QuestionAccordion` component *outside* of the `App` component and it should behave normally.  For example:

```
const QuestionAccordion = ({
  dueAccordionOpen,
  handleAccordionChange,
  questionsMap
}: {
  dueAccordionOpen: boolean;
  handleAccordionChange: (val: QuestionTypes) => void;
  questionsMap: any;
}) => { ... }

export const App = () => { ... }
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-animation-problem-forked-msohg6?file=/src/App.tsx:995-1021

Comment: Thanks! That works. Although I still don't entirely understand why it's a problem, is the component re-rendering on the click? I thought that would only happen if the props change. Do you have an article or link that would further explain why this happens?